Is there a way to use Material Design icons in a Qt Quick (QML) file?
I'm working on a Qt project based on Qt 6.7.2 and using QML for the frontend and Python for the backend.
I'm wondering if there is a way to use material design icons directly in a QML file, and if it's included in QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.3 like the themes and colors. I didn't find any informations online.
Thanks

On Qt 5.12 I did it by converting to svg's and using a theme: https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-icons.html. I assume it's still the same in Qt 6, but not sure 100%

@Amfasis I decided to just add svg in my project when I need them, I just wanted to know if there was an already integrated solution in Qt but it seems there is not
